# QPainter not drawing text properly

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am not able to draw path using QPainter drawText() method

```
QString Path = "/home/User"
QPainter *painter    
QRectF centerRect = QRectF (textX,centerY + m_bounds.height()*0.15, fm.width(Path),fm.height());
painter->drawText(centerRect,Path,QTextOption(Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter  ));
```

In windows its drawing the text but on ubunthu Linux its showing only /home

Comment: not drawing properly , how dose it drawing? tell in depth

Comment: `Path` in drawtext should change to `path`

Answer (score 0):

```
QFontMetrics fm = painter->fontMetrics();

qreal centerY = ( m_bounds.height()  -  fm.height() -10  )/2;
qreal textX = 8;

QRectF centerRect = QRectF (textX,centerY + m_bounds.height()*0.15, fm.width(m_folderPath),fm.height());
painter->drawText(centerRect,m_folderPath,QTextOption(Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter  ));

fm.width(m_folderPath)
```

shows differnet value for /home/user and /homeuser4